# Can not automatically make field on macOS

Tags: splunk

When I insert CSV data into Splunk. 
data can not be recognized in Splunk 
I tried to insert same data on windows laptop, that's no problem. 
my mac setted UTF-8  I don't know how can I do that 
data.csv is saved as UTF-8 also maybe my mac has problem with encoding characters

[image]

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK9k3.png)

macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the `CHARSET` to `UTF-16`?

Alternatively, can you run from the OSX commandline

```
file -I filename.csv
```

and use whatever charset the `file` command identified